# Constructing a multipart/form-data request for transmitting a PDF to an external service

Tags: apex, httprequest, fileupload

I'm trying to make a POST request to [this specific endpoint](https://developer.ilovepdf.com/docs/api-reference#upload) from Apex to include what is required; a task Id and a single file. It has been very difficult.

At first, Bad Request responses was all I got, but after fiddling around with things such as `\r\n` in the construction of the blob, I started getting Internal Server Errors.

My code below is mostly thanks to [this post](https://blog.enree.co/2013/01/salesforce-apex-post-mutipartform-data.html) by Enrico Murro, however he only includes a file without any additional parameters (there is a comment on that post by Vinod with a possible solution by Enrico, but I couldn't understand it, maybe someone here can).

Here is how I have constructed the blob. If anyone has any expertise regarding the matter, please please share!

```
String boundary = '----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW';
String preheader = '--'+boundary+'\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="task"\n'+taskId;
String header = '--'+boundary+'\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="'+file_name+'";\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream';

String headerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(preheader+header+'\r\n\r\n'));
while (headerEncoded.endsWith('=')) {
    header += ' ';
    headerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(header+'\r\n\r\n'));}
    
String bodyEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(file_body);
Blob bodyBlob = null;
String last4Bytes = bodyEncoded.substring(bodyEncoded.length()-4,bodyEncoded.length());
String footer = '--'+boundary+'--';
if (last4Bytes.endsWith('==')) {
    last4Bytes = last4Bytes.substring(0,2) + '0K';
    bodyEncoded = bodyEncoded.substring(0,bodyEncoded.length()-4) + last4Bytes;
} else if (last4Bytes.endsWith('=')) {
    last4Bytes = last4Bytes.substring(0,3) + 'N';
    bodyEncoded = bodyEncoded.substring(0,bodyEncoded.length()-4) + last4Bytes;
    footer = '\n' + footer;
} else {footer = '\r\n' + footer;}

String footerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(footer));
bodyBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(headerEncoded+bodyEncoded+footerEncoded);

HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setHeader('Content-Type','multipart/form-data; boundary='+boundary);
for (String key : headerMap.keySet()) System.debug(key + ': ' + headerMap.get(key));
if (headerMap != null) for (String key : headerMap.keySet()) req.setHeader(key, headerMap.get(key));
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setEndpoint(url);
req.setBodyAsBlob(bodyBlob);
req.setTimeout(120000);

Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
```

After a lot of meddling around, I ended up with the following method of simply prepending the `preheader` string which is my additional parameter to the `headerEncoded` string. I've tried the placement of this additional parameter all over and around the body before and after constructing the blob, but to no avail.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Maybe it would help someone else encountering this issue. I decided to pivot and try something completely different, so this issue is no longer of concern for my use case.